# Java exception in loop

Tags: java, exception

```
Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);

public void menu() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Your options is:");
            int option = 0;
            option = b.nextInt();
            b.nextLine();

            if (option == 1)
                add();
            else if (option == 2)
                delete();
            else if (option == 3)
                print();
            else if (option == 4)
                nr();
            else if (option == 0)
                break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Not a valid option!");
            // break;
        }
    }
    b.close();
}
```

Thing is that whenever I'm giving something else than the selected options(0,1,2,3,4) the function prints the message from the `catch` and then asks for a new option but this thing is done repeatedly. If the `break` is there, the whole execution is stopped and all I want is to ask again for an option but without the infinite loop. For example, if I type a "r" instead of a number, it should catch the exception and get again through the `while`.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental purpose of `try...catch` is to `try` to execute code that could throw an exception, and if it *does* throw the exception, `catch` it and deal with it.

Invalid input in this case won't throw an exception, unless they managed to sneak a character in there, which would result in an infinite loop.

Instead of assuming that the user will enter in a digit - which is what `Scanner#nextInt` generally assumes - read the whole line instead, and use `Integer.parseInt()` to construct the `int`.

```
option = Integer.parseInt(b.nextLine());
```

If this blows up because someone decided to put "foo" instead of "1", then you'll hit your exceptional case, and be able to re-enter values again.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
try
{
  do
  {
   option=b.nextInt();
   // continue

   switch(option){


        case 0:  
                 break;
        case 1:  add();
                 break;
        case 2:  delete();
                 break;
        case 3:  print();
                 break;
        case 4:  nr();
                 break;
        default: System.out.println("Not a valid option!");
                 break;

   }

  }while(!(option==1||option==2||option==3||option==4))
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Please enter a number");
}
```

Comment: What happens if I enter in a series of letters?

Answer (score 0):

solved it.I added a `b.nextLine();` in the catch and the loop stops.